# Windows Forms C# create control Category List

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

I created own control using Windows Forms under C# project. I use Settings to change control properties like:

```
[Category("Settings")]
public Color BorderColor { get; set; }
```

and in my form I just change BorderColor by picking another from list.

But now I want to make NewList (of strings) in Form and then bind my ListString attribute to my NewList.

In my control it looks like:

```
[Category("Settings")]
public List<string> ListString { get; set; }
```

In my form it looks like

```
public List<string> NewList = new List<string>() { "1", "2" };
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: I bind my ListString to NewList with  Control.ListString = NewList;, but in designer I don't have bind. I know it's ok, because I do it from c# code, but how to make better bind from designer?

Comment: You don't need to do that manually, in Project->Settings, you can add a StringCollection in the settings, and you can add "1", "2" with design support, which will be serialized into xml.